Преобразовать данные в куки C#
У нас есть данные твиттер аккаунта, мы используем Playwright C# чтобы автоматизировать определенные действия на аккаунте, как реализовать автологин при помощи преобразования данных (Логин, пароль и почта) в cookie для автоматического входа в аккаунт.
При этом исходные данные не преобразованы в необходимый формат, тк мы так и не выяснили есть ли метод шифрования данных под стандарт chrome версии 124 и старше

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

"Мы", "Мы", "Мы"... Я вижу сейчас одного конкретного человека, который задает вопрос, о каких "МЫ" может идти речь? Вы этим только путаете тех, кто читает. Далее, "Playwright" - это "инструмент для тестирования", вы тестируете свой сайт? Нет... Не стоит использовать целый браузер для парсинга информации, научитесь работать с запросами, с API. Далее, раз вы используете целый браузер, то вытягивайте из него нужные куки, сохраняйте где надо и используйте где надо, в чем проблема? Про "исходные данные" я вообще ничего не понял...

Куки генерирует сервер.
